# Does the size of my snake matter?

Tags: slither.io

I've been playing [slither.io](http://slither.io) lately and I've been wondering if my size matters. I can't see the impact of size in the game, except the leaderboards.

Does size of my snake matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Length is beneficial, girth is a hindrance. They both scale together though.

Length allows you to encircle and kill smaller snakes by forcing them into a small space they cannot escape from.

Girth reduces your 'turning circle'. Although you can turn just as quickly as other snakes, your freedom of movement is restricted - a common way for larger snakes to die is if they have two snakes either side of their head, leaving them no way to turn out of danger.

If you want to stay safe in the late-game (20k+ in size), the only way to reliably do so is to move in a large circle, following your own tail, so you always have one side of you clear to turn into if someone tries to attack you. Your rate of growth is relatively slow, you can only eat what you happen to go past in your big circular route, and you can't stray out too far from your own path without getting into danger, but if you are conservative in your risk-taking you can grow to essentially any size if you're careful with this strategy.

Comment: Great answer! So if I got you right, size has both pros and cons. I'll wait a bit and will accept this as answer.

Comment: `Q: Does the size of my snake matter? A: Length is beneficial, girth is a hindrance.` It's amazing what a lack of context can do to connotation :D

Answer (score 1):

**The size of a snake matters deeply.**

---

#### Reasons

The size of a snake in slither.io matters a bunch not only about the game purpose, but:

- **Advantage.** 
  You can easily trap a tiny worm player inside a big hole and kill it for dots easily if you're large.
- **Fear.** 
  Players can look at the leaderboard and see that your at least too big for them, so they can try to stay away from you.
- **Chaser** 
  Instead of you to be running from big worms, you can actually chase them and have a bit fun.

**NOTE:**  Players even as the tiniest worms can defeat you, players can stay away from you and at the same time eat dots, and players can turn around and defeat you unnoticed.

---

Answer (score -2):

Size of your snake doesn't matter.

How? Any way and any How on any size you can stop any size snake
But as you keep small you cannot trap a big snake but you still can manage to
stop them. As a big snake may feel like it matters about trap little snakes but you may have been stopped by a snake that is 10X smaller then you.

A .io is trying to be fun and trying to make the player think of what to do for the next move the player will take to try to get bigger even thought it doesn't matter, size will rank you up on the leader boards and it dose make you feel nice that the name on the snake and you are on the leader boards but it may only be on there for a short time from small snakes that want to take down big snakes.

It is really your thinking if you think size matters or not, Many players don't care about size and some do.

Comment: Are you saying that it's not about the size of your snake, but rather how you use it?